# Is there a default icon for WPF apps similar to Winforms apps?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icons

Currently my WPF apps have the "unknown document" type of icons. I don't want to design icons for each but something like the default icon for Winform apps would be very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the windows icon for each window (or at least for your main window). This is the icon that is shown in the windows title and in task-manager. Be aware that the window icon should not be an .ico-file having huge resolution icons, else it will fail on windows XP. You can also use a png-file.

```
<Window 
  ...
  Icon="/Assembly;component/imagePath/yourImage.png"
  Title="Window Title"...>
```

The other icon is the icon in the projects properties page. This icon is used as the file icon. You must use an .ico-file. However for this, you can use also highres icon-files (for showing huge icons in Vista+ -explorer).

Comment: Thanks, I thought wpf would at least have a usable icon if you don't provide one.